# how do i make sure users can't enter in duplicates?

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates

Spent all day on this one. I have an array of expenses that populates my tableview. Users can select a row from the tableview to edit the expense, which includes the name, the amount, the due date, etc.

I don't want users to be able to enter in a duplicate name. What I mean is, I want to check their input against the array to make sure the name doesn't already exist. This sounds simple to me, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

**CODE #1:**

```
    var duplicateCount = 0
    for item in Expense.expensesArray.filter({ $0.ownerName == currentUserName }).filter({ $0.category == expense?.category }) {
        if item.expenseName != expense?.expenseName {
            print("no duplicates found in \(item.expenseName). moving on")
        } else if item.expenseName == expense?.expenseName {
            duplicateCount += 1
            print("duplicate found in \(item.expenseName)")
        }
    }
```

**CODE #2:** (which is pretty similar to #1)

```
    var duplicatesAmount: Int = 0
    for expense in Expense.expensesArray.filter({ return $0.ownerName == currentUserName }).filter({ $0.category == expense?.category }) {
        if expense.expenseName.lowercased() == expenseNameTextField.text?.lowercased() {
            duplicatesAmount += 1
            print("POTENTIAL DUPLICATE #\(duplicatesAmount): ",expense.expenseName)
        }
    }
    // if there is more than one expense in the array with the same name, return true
    if duplicatesAmount > 1 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

EDIT: The code runs whether there's a duplicate or not. It never sees the duplicate, even if I purposely put one in.

UPDATE: This worked.

```
if expense?.expenseName == expenseNameTextField.text {
        updateExpenseInfo()
    } else {
        // iterate over the array and see if new name is found anywhere
        let dupArray = Expense.expensesArray.filter({ $0.ownerName == currentUserName && $0.category == expense?.category && $0.expenseName == expenseNameTextField.text })
        if dupArray.isEmpty {
            updateExpenseInfo()
        } else {
            duplicateNameAlert()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what way doesn't the posted code work? Be clear and specific about the issues you are having.

Comment: Okay, forgot. Noob mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
struct Object {
    let name: String
    let amount: Int

    init(name: String = "", amount: Int = 0) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}

let a = Object(name: "Foo", amount: 10)
let b = Object(name: "Bar", amount: 20)

let array = [a, b]

func contains(value: String) -> Bool {
    return array.filter({ $0.name == value }).isEmpty
}

print(contains(value: "Foo")) // true
print(contains(value: "Test")) // false
```

So you basically just add the `contains` function and return `array.filter({ $0.name == value }).isEmpty`. If it returns true then save otherwise don´t save. The value you pass it the entered value.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: The problem is that it will always return true because the original array has the item in it. So if I user goes to change the name of the item, I want to check to see if the array has the new name anywhere...

Comment: I don´t really get it, you got two arrays? Why not just use one? Try to add run the code in my example in your Playground and you´ll see how it works. I don´t think you need two separate arrays for the thing you´re trying to do @PhontaineJudd

Comment: Yep, your suggestion worked. Thanks. I was just overthinking it and making it too complex. I ended up using slightly different code, but your suggestion did in fact work. I'll post what I ended up using.

Comment: Take into account that when the array scales up, say 1000 records, filtering objects becomes inefficient, you might want to hold additional dictionary to check existence of items. Test with: dictionary[name] != nil, then item already in the data source